# Illegal start of expression while trying to multiply?

Tags: java

I'm just starting to learn Java, and i ran into a problem while trying to multiply.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kertolasku {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please give a number");

        int first = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please give another number");

        int second = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        int v = first*second;

        System.out.println(first + " * " + *second + " = ");



        // toteuta ohjelma tänne

    }
}
```

I've been stuck on this for about an hour or two. I have no idea on what to do. May someone help me please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: typo - remove the `*` from `*second`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `*` before `second` in the last line and add `+ v` too so you actually get the result afterwards.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kertolasku {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please give a number");

        int first = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Please give another number");

        int second = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        int v = first*second;

        System.out.println(first + " * " + second + " = " + v);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i didn't even know it can multiply the numbers without the actual "*" in it. It's my 2nd day of learning Java and i basically know nothing yet. Without your answer i would have been stuck here for a while!

Comment: @Lerby No problemo, glad I could help. If it worked don't forget to click the tick under the score of the answer to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
System.out.println(first + " * " + *second + " = ");
```

remove the `*` from `*second`:

```
System.out.println(first + " * " + second + " = ");
```

Also, if you want to print out the result, add the `v` in the string:

```
System.out.println(first + " * " + *second + " = " + v);
```